# Using Phonegap, is it possible to detect if someone brings an iPhone up to their mouth

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

Using Phonegap, is it possible to detect if someone brings an iPhone up toward their mouth? Or is this necessary to do in native code?

Comment: why would anyone do that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With phonegap you do have acces to the accelometer and the mic. I suppose you can use a combination of these inputs to determine roughly if someone put their phone close to their mouth. Native or phonegap the mathematical challenge will be near identical.

Reaearch:

1 - Cordova Media Capture API for audio

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture

2 - Accelometer

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html

Have fun :)